# Addeventlistener fallback for older IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, addeventlistener, attachevent

I am trying to create a simple fallback function, which will make sure addeventlistener will work in IE versions older than 9.

So far i have this

```
if (!Element.prototype.addEventListener)
{ 
     Element.prototype.addEventListener =
           function(ev, fc)
            {
                xxx.attachEvent('on' + ev, fc);
            }
}
```

The problem is, that I don't know how to get the reference to the element to which the event is being attached to. (the xxx)

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ `this`.